# PHP mysql_real_escape_string or alternative with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm trying to migrate a lot of old PHP mysql prodecural function like `mysql_query`, `mysql_real_escape_string` etc. into PDO with **minimum effort**. I don't want to rewrite every old DB function. The reason is that it's rather an old application and I'm developing a new module into it and want to use PDO there.

So now I'm porting these old functions into PDO methods - I apended `_port` to my old functions so I use `mysql_query_port`, `mysql_fetch_array_port`, `mysql_num_rows_port` and `mysql_real_escape_string_port`.

The first three works pretty good:

```
function mysql_query_port($query) {
    $db = Database::instance();
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);

    if (!$statement->execute())
        return false;
    return $statement;
}

function mysql_fetch_array_port(PDOStatement $statement) {
    return $statement->fetch();
}

function mysql_num_rows_port(PDOStatement $statement) {
    return $statement->rowCount();
}
```

The problem is with `mysql_real_escape_string` - I can't use it when I don't have mysql connection. So please help me decide what to do (or find a bug in my code):

1. Init `mysql_pconnect()` at the beginning of the script so that I can still use `mysql_real_escape_string` (I won't be doing any queries through that connection).
2. Write some alternative. The [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) says this function "prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, , ', " and \x1a.", so I came up with this:

.

```
function mysql_real_escape_string_port($string) {
    return addcslashes ($string, "\x00\n\r\\'\"\x1a");
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, does the MySQL PDO driver implement PDO::quote?

Comment: you would be way better off with using prepared statements with PDO rather than trying to figure out how to escape the statements. Both in terms of code readability and application security.

Comment: Corbin : Yes, it does. But it also places quotes around the string literal which mysql_escape_string() does not.

Comment: Well, if I delete the first and last character from PDO::quote() result, I could have the same result as mysql_real_escape_string(). Am I right?

Comment: Aurimas: I agree with you it's not a good way. But going through 5000 lines of db functions seems like a nightmare to me. Knowing that the application will be rewriten to Scala and Cassandra in a year or so.

Comment: What is the reason for such a migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` requires a connection because its output depends on the connection character set.

If you are able to sync character sets manually (or if you never change it), you may write your own implementation.

Comment: So do you recommend NOT to keep one PDO and one mysql_pconnect together? I hope I can sync character sets manually.

Comment: @koubic: having a dedicated mysql connection just to use it a storage for character set is a bit of an overkill in my opinion. If you are reluctant to used prepared statements (which `PDO` is for) and just want to pretend it's `php:mysql`, just implement your own `real_escape_string`. If you are not using multibyte character sets, it's as simple as escaping those seven special characters.

Comment: @koubic having a dedicated mysql connection just to use it as a storage for character set is the same nonsense as just a mechanical replacement mysql_* with pdo*, turning PDO into the same procedural mess. Two nonsenses at once is going to be a little too much.

Comment: Thanks. I'm keen to use PDO in new modules but reluctant to rewrite all existing code into PDO and then test every single functionality in the application. I'm gonna use PDO::quote and cut first and last char as an alternative to `mysql_real_escape_string`. And every time I do some modification to old code, I rewrite it to PDO. So eventually, the old code will die out.

Comment: @koubic rewriting bare mysql API functions calls with bare PDO API methods calls still makes no sense.

Comment: But it saves lots of work (i believe days). I tested it now and rewriting the methods in PDO makes the script 30% slower :( that makes me think of rewriting it, but not doing it yet